# reducing the size of lm object

Tags: r, lm, stargazer

I'm having a data frame of about 50000 lines, and i'm running a lm command over it with about 5000 estimators. 
My PC is OK with it, But the LM objecct itself turn to be too big. and than in the second regression I'm getting the error of:

```
cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-___-gb
```

I'd like to use Stargaze and combine many regression result but I have not succeed so far.

the approach to removing the qr$qr [here](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/reducing-your-r-memory-footprint-by-7000x.html)  seems to ruin the ability to make something like:

```
summary(fit)
stargazer(fit)
```

Can I save only the data needed for the Stargaze and than remove the object? 
and aggregate it after I'm finishing with all the regressions?

I tried to do so but I get duplicates of the first column. 
and anyway, I'm sure there are much better approaches

```
data(trees)

a<-log(Volume)~ log(Height) + log(Girth)
b<-log(Volume)~ log(Height) + Girth

aa <- lm(a, data=trees)
bb <- lm(b, data=trees)

bbb<-stargazer(aa,type="text")
bbb<-stargazer(bb,type="text")

cbind(aaa,bbb)
```

Comment: Try: convert character strings into factors, or use just a matrix rather than a data frame if your data only contains numbers. Remove all columns you don't need for regression. Would this help?

Comment: All 5,000 estimators and un-correlated with eachother?

Comment: @jaySf, I've tried that but that didn't help me...

Comment: @Sam they probably are in a way,
It is a interaction of 2 var that used as a Fixed Effects, 
so it might be correlated.

Comment: Maybe try reducing the size by removing correlated predictors?

Comment: I beleive I can't do this as the FE is intended to deal with endogeneity my data has.

Comment: you could try adding `model=FALSE` so the data is not returned.

Comment: thx @user20650, I've tried that, but that dind't change much.
It's worth mentioning that most of the size is in the qr$qr,
but once I delete it, I'm no longer able to make a regression output.